# how to validate 2 dates (cannot be different months)

Tags: sql, date, validation, datediff, dayofmonth

| firstDate | secondDate |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-12-02 | 2023-01-02 |
| .. | ... |

the second date of the month follows the first date of the month, so the month of the date is can't be different

result like this :
| firstDate | secondDate |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-12-02 | 2023-12-02 |
|  | ... |

If any body knows the query please share.

Comment: secondate is same as firstday ?. share your expected result

Comment: hy, my expected result is @firstDate = '2022-12-02' and 'secondDate = '2023-12-02', if the input month is different then it cannot be entered/insert

Answer (score 0):

Compare the month and perhaps the day as well (pseudo code):

```
Month(firstDate) = Month(secondDate) and
Day(firstDate) = Day(secondDate)
```